# Under what conditions can I take duty free liquids from outside the EU through EU airport security?

Tags: transit, airport-security, eu, duty-free

In know that if I buy duty free liquids in one EU airport, and have them sealed in the special security bags with the receipt shown, I can take them through security at other EU airports the same day. [Details on Europa.eu](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/safety/air-security/index_en.htm). (With the proviso that they'll probably be subject to additional screenings or inspection, and may be removed from their bags then re-sealed again in a new one, which will take extra time)

On an upcoming journey, I'll be flying from outside the EU into one EU airport, then connecting onto a different EU airport which is my final destination. For the intra-EU leg, I won't be able to buy the cheaper "real" duty free, as I'll have arrived in the EU customs area by that point.

Given that, if I want to buy something, the place would be at my non-EU departure airport. However, I'll be transiting on the way, and having to re-clear security.

What are the rules on non-EU purchased duty free in security sealed bags, going through transfer security at an EU airport? Is it treated the same as EU purchased duty free? Is it always allowed? Only allowed from certain origin airports?

(I've found [this Europa.eu page from 2013](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/aviation-security-policy/lags_en.htm) which lists some allowed non-EU countries, but also says that changes are coming, and it's 2 years later! [This other Europa.eu page](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/safety/air-security/index_en.htm) covers departures from EU airports, but not my case, and I couldn't spot any others.)

Answer (score 5):

You can take them provided they're packed in a sealed tamper-evident bag, with a receipt inside the bag. Also, it's better if they're bought just prior to flight.
During security check they must be presented for separate inspection. Liquids might be  removed from the bag, scanned, and repacked in a new bag, which can take up to 5-10 minutes depending on the airport.

Sources: experience, [EU Regulation 185/2010](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1450405347112&uri=CELEX:32010R0185)

Other revelant links: 
[EU airport security rules page at europa.eu](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/safety/air-security/index_en.htm)

[EU Regulation 300/2008](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1450405451109&uri=CELEX:32008R0300)

Comment: can you link EU Regulation 185/2010? and i will give the bounty

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis Post edited fo include revelant links