# Can I bring duty free liquids through LIM-CDG-LHR?

Tags: transit, duty-free

Similar to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11572/can-i-connect-through-the-usa-with-liquid-duty-free-purchases) regarding transit on a DUB-ORD-PDX route, can I make duty-free purchases (e.g. alcohol) in Lima, and return with it to London via Paris (LIM-CDG-LHR), and bring the liquids with me?

I also note that [this (unanswered) question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52301/under-what-conditions-can-i-take-duty-free-liquids-from-outside-the-eu-through-e) is similar, though less specific about the intermediate airport.  I don't know whether that would make a difference (i.e. whether individual airports have different mechanisms which might specifically allow or preclude such a thing).

[The UK Government web site's advice](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/peru/entry-requirements) is vague on the subject, while [ifly](http://www.ifly.com/eu-travel-rules) says that it simply can't be done without the liquids being confiscated.

The value of the drink is unlikely to be sufficient to make it worth buying a suitcase at CDG and checking that in, though a collapsible holdall might be one solution, if that's a possibility.  I just find it frustrating that something which should be easy is made so difficult.

[Edit]
The return flights (AF483 and AF1080) both use terminal 2E at CDG, which (according the the easycdg site in DCTLib's answer) means I'll definitely be going through a security check.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That author seems overly sensationalist, and ignores the fact that airlines will do their own screening in addition to airport screening.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The comments on that article make it quite clear that this is specific to flights to the US from Central and South America and some other places; the asker isn't going to the US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the duty-free liquid is in a sealed plastic bag, with the receipt clearly visible, and you do not open the bag, you should be fine:

http://www.airfrance.us/US/en/common/guidevoyageur/pratique/bagage_transport_liquide_airfrance.htm

> On board your connecting flight departing from the European Union, you may transport duty-free liquids purchased at your departure airport or on board, as long as they remain in a sealed plastic bag. You must keep the receipt and make sure it is clearly displayed in the sealed bag. The receipt must list the airport or airline company through which your purchase was made.

Similar rules are in place in the United States:

http://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/liquids-rule

> You may carry liquids more than 3.4 oz or 100 ml in your carry-on bag if:
>
> - You are traveling internationally to the United States with a connecting flight.
> - They are in transparent containers.
> - You bought them at a duty-free shop where it is packed in a secure, tamper-evident bag.

Answer (score 4):

Update on April 2018. 
My flight was from San Jose - Costa Rica (SJO) with the first change in Panama (PTY), the second in Paris (CDG), heading to Poland (WAW).
I've just passed the security check in Paris with the 0,5 bottle of rum packed in sealed (transparent) bag at the duty-free shop at SJO Airport. The receipt was entered in the bag (but not sealed together). It has alerted the French officer but eventually, this wasn't the problem. The security crew repacked the bottle in their own (official) bag and sealed it together with the original receipt inside.
Based on my experience there is no reason to worry. Duty-free item can transfer through CDG without any problems when basic security principles are maintained.

Answer (score 1):

The CDG web page has a nice website for flight connections that also states whether you have to go though a security check. If that is the case, liquids will be problematic.

http://easycdg.com/passenger-information/connecting-flight-connections-paris-cdg-airport/where-to-go/